Package and use source files with PyInstaller?
My app auto-updates by:

regularly checking for new versions of my app on PyPi,
downloading and extracting the latest one,
replacing the source files, and restarting.

My project has the following structure:
app.py
project/
    utils.py
    core.py

New versions are automatically downloaded from PyPi with pip download  --no-deps --no-binary :all: project==X.X.X, this downloads the project-X.X.X.tar.gz which is extracted and replaces the above project/ folder. The app is then restarted.
Now when I package my project with PyInstaller, it compiles everything into an executable so there are no sources to be replaced.
Is it possible to have the project sources in the _internal folder created by PyInstaller, and have them used, instead of having everything compiled in the executable?

You can add the command --contents-directory="." to enable the old onedir layout without contents directory. Check the doc.
pyinstaller --contents-directory="." main.py


Or you can downgrade PyInstaller to 5.9.0 which uses such onedir layout by default.
